# Issue of Superman Adventures where Livewire was convoyed in a yellow truck?

Tags: dc, episode-identification

I remember an issue of *Superman Adventures* where Livewire were convoyed inside of a yellow truck, probably there was also parademons in that issue. Could you help to find what exact (number) issue that was?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*Superman Adventures #65*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Adventures_Vol_1_65)

[image]